# Relationship of Niece's Daughter of my blood related Aunt's Husband

Tags: kinship-terminology

What is our relationship?

John is my Uncle (non blood) married to my aunt Barbera (blood).

Ashley was my Uncle John's niece (blood)

Ashley died a few months ago leaving behind a little girl, last week that little girls father died. Now she is with Ashley's mom who for medical reasons is unable to care for her. And her father's side doesn't want her. I'd like to get guardianship of her, and I was hoping if we are considered family it might make it more favorable supposed to foster care.

Non-Blood Uncle John->Uncles John's Blood Related Niece Ashley->Daughter of Ashley.

Comment: Chris, welcome to Genealogy & Family History, please be sure to review the [tour] and [help] section of this site to understand the format of well formed questions and especially the title as this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: This is not a genealogy question - however you may get a useful answer at [Law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Chris, I am not a lawyer, and we are family historians.  In any case we can't give legal advice because we are not your lawyers. You consider her family, which is the important thing.  Please get legal help from someone qualified to practice in your area. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The daughter of Ashley is no blood or legal relationship to you in the United States unless otherwise supplemented by another legal document such as a will or other court executed document.

The daughter of Ashley is basically just a family acquaintance, or simply's your Uncles's nieces's daughter on his side of the family.